# What kind of information can I use when trying to convince my bank to lower the interest rate on my line of credit?

Tags: canada, banking, interest-rate, negotiation, line-of-credit

I'm looking to lower the interest rate on my line of credit, and, before calling up my bank, I am wondering what kind of information I should have prepared that I can use as arguments when trying to convince them to do this?

Comment: Ramit Sethi has [a good post about negotiating credit card APR](http://www.iwillteachyoutoberich.com/blog/lower-credit-card-apr/). Not sure whether you'd have the same success with your credit line, but it's worth a read, along with the linked excerpts from his book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having another source of lower interest credit, i.e. be prepared, if you are able, to be willing to shut down your line with this bank. Short of this, discussing your record of on time payments, current credit score, etc, may help.